# Faraday tensor, antisymmetric electromagnetic tensor

Tags: special-relativity

I want to write $F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}$ in terms of $F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}$. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The two expressions you wrote down are the same because for each pair $(\mu,\nu)$, the quantities $F^{\mu\nu}$ and $F_{\mu\nu}$ are real numbers and can be commuted past one another.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for asking

Comment: @JishnuRay No need to apologize; even the best of us miss basic stuff.